# Compare source files on function level

Tags: string-comparison, delta

I would like to compare two source files. While the output will return the functions that were changed. And not the lines.

My question is, what is the best why to find the start of a function and the end of it. If you know the row number.

Source files are in c.

Example

File Old

```
#include <stdio.h>

void checkPrimeNumber();

int main()
{
    checkPrimeNumber();    // no argument is passed to prime()
    return 0;
}

void checkPrimeNumber()
{
    int flag=0;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");

}
```

file New

```
#include <stdio.h>

void checkPrimeNumber();

int main()
{
    checkPrimeNumber();    // no argument is passed to prime()
    return 0;
}

void checkPrimeNumber()
{
    int flag=1;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");

}
```

Change is in fileNew **flag=1**;

Result will be

```
void checkPrimeNumber()
{
    int flag=1;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is kind of a mission statement or maybe a request for code to be written. As such it is not a *question about programming*.

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: hi @FelixPalmen if you can provide feedback or direct me in to a solution that would be great

Comment: just edited my question, My question is, what is the best why to find the start of a function and the end of it. If you know the row number.

Comment: Not to sound to harsh, but if you need to ask how, it's probably out of your expertise level. Sounds like you need a complete C parser.

Comment: Maybe just use a tool that already does this, like `diff -p`.

Comment: thank @FelixPalmen, but need to run it from python on windows